# Creating Task scheduler with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm not even sure if this is possible because I'm not familiar with JavaScript at all.

Here is the scenario:

We have an internal site where users schedule a special meeting. The site uses JavaScript and sends Outlook invitations for the user to accept and add it to their Outlook calendar.

To prepare for the meeting, the users have to run an executable on their computer that was built internally a day before the meeting. But some users forget to do it and show up unprepared. What I'm trying to do is add a scheduled task along with the invitation that's being sent and runs the executable on their computer the day before.

Is this possible to do and if it is, can anyone share a simple code to add it the existing code we already have in place?

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Please [do some research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) before asking a question on Stack Overflow. Asking volunteers to write a task scheduler for you seems very disrespectful of their time.

Comment: Thanks! Seriously you think I just popped in here and wrote a question? I already did the research and couldn't find anything. Don't need you to point out the obvious!

Comment: It's not obvious to many, many, depressingly many, people... Please [edit] your question to show that research, and to show how you've attempted to solve the issue yourself.